# Can't install ROS on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: robotic-arm, raspberrypi, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following this tutorial on how to install ROS on an ARM device.

Part of the problem is that Ubuntu 14.04 is not an install option for Raspberry Pi 3. What they support is Ubuntu MATE (15.04). Any ideas of how to get around this?

The error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-ros-base : Depends: ros-indigo-actionlib but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ros-indigo-bond-core but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ros-indigo-class-loader but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ros-indigo-dynamic-reconfigure but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ros-indigo-nodelet-core but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ros-indigo-pluginlib but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ros-indigo-ros-core but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231216/can%27t-install-ros-on-raspberry-pi-3/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-04-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on 2016-04-06**:
If you get desperate, you could install ubuntu 14.04 within a chroot environment. http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingIndigoInChroot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't install packages that are intended for 14.04 on a different version of Ubuntu. There will be version conflicts and missing dependencies.

There are already four other questions that address this issue. Perhaps one of their solutions will work for you?

http://answers.ros.org/question/231041/solved-install-ros-indigo-on-raspberypi3b-under-raspbian-jessie/

http://answers.ros.org/question/230076/ros-on-raspberry-3/

http://answers.ros.org/question/229860/ros-running-on-raspberry-pi-3/

http://answers.ros.org/question/228883/ros-with-raspberry-pi-3/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys, I saw these posts recently and I too was trying to install not only ROS but also mavros on my new Raspberry Pi 3 but just like you guys, any of the wiki link did not work directly for me. So, I followed a combination of few steps from the above pages and also others and have documented everything in the PDF [link is below]. These steps worked for me and I was able to install ROS Kinect on Raspberry Pi 3.

Just to give a heads up- If you are trying to get ROS Indigo, you can only install a few individual packages as I tried or only ros-comm. If you want more features then I'm sorry ROS Indigo will not work on R-Pi3. You can try my steps and let me know if you face problems some where. It worked for me and believe me I spent a minimum 50+ hours figuring all this out!

link:[https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4lNqhhSk7SQLVNZYzBZbm9mUG8]

---

Originally posted by [audia8.sid](https://answers.ros.org/users/27291/audia8.sid/) with karma: 46 on 2016-06-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-06-27**:
Hey thanks for posting all your hard work up here! I ended up getting a Jetson TK1 so fortunately I was able to keep ROS Indigo.

**Comment by [audia8.sid](https://answers.ros.org/users/27291/audia8.sid/) on 2016-06-27**:
Haha! no worries.. And great that you are not stuck there.

**Comment by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) on 2016-10-01**:
Great work.  I would love to follow your guide, but not being able to copy and paste the command lines from pdf makes it a lot harder.

**Comment by [audia8.sid](https://answers.ros.org/users/27291/audia8.sid/) on 2016-10-01**:
Hi. I don't get why you are not being able to copy-paste the lines! You could download the file and should be able to do that. If not, can you elaborate what exactly is the problem you are facing or maybe email me, I can send you the doc file if you want. Let me know!

Cheers
Sid

**Comment by [Ashkr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45549/ashkr/) on 2019-11-03**:
hi @audia8.sid, thanks for your post. in my case is shows NO PACKAGE OGRE, OGRE-Overlay found. Please help. Error log: https://pastebin.com/NSwrJxcA

**Comment by [audia8.sid](https://answers.ros.org/users/27291/audia8.sid/) on 2019-11-04**:
Hi @Ashkr I haven't verified this for quite some time now but last I checked the ROS installation was pretty straight forward on RPi 3 with then latest Raspbian

**Comment by [Ashkr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45549/ashkr/) on 2019-11-04**:
@audia8.sid, thanks for your reply!
could you please check my error log related to 'rviz package failure' and correct me where I am mistaken?
Also i am on Raspbian buster latest. Please guide! Thanks

**Comment by [audia8.sid](https://answers.ros.org/users/27291/audia8.sid/) on 2019-11-04**:
I am not sure; are you installing on a fresh/clean OS? And which version of ROS are you trying to install? Try following [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi) wiki page which says it was last updated on 2019-09-26. It should help you install ROS on your RPi.
For your particular error, it looks like some version error for something, a google search "No package 'OGRE' found" led me [here](https://forums.ogre3d.org/viewtopic.php?t=91701). It says try to comment the line `findOGRE` in the cmake script. Hope this helps!
Cheers

**Comment by [Ashkr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45549/ashkr/) on 2019-11-04**:
@audia8.sid: I followed the same link you mentioned to install ROS on RPi3.
Yes, its clean fresh OS!
How can i check ROS version. I followed as mentioned in http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi

may i please know where this 'cmake script' located, Is it in /ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz; here i can see these listed....couldnt see 'findOGRE' line even in 'CMakeLists.txt'

**CHANGELOG.rst
cmake
CMakeLists.txt
default.rviz
doc
help
icons
images
image_src
mainpage.dox
ogre_media
package.xml
plugin_description.xml
README.md
rosdoc.yaml
rviz.sublime-project
scripts
setup.py
src**

**Comment by [Ashkr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45549/ashkr/) on 2019-11-18**:
@audia8.sid: please help!